# Delphi application suddenly reports Invalid ImageList

Tags: delphi

I have an application that has been running for 10+ years. It's written in Delphi 6.

Last week a customer reported an application error on reading a specific Imagelist.

While I can understand such errors during development, I do not understand why such error suddenly appears in an application where imagelists should be compiled in. Especially one that has not been touched for years.

Can anything in the windows / language environment influence reading on ImageLists that are compiled into the EXE ?  The customer is using Korean windows.  Or is there other places to look for the reason ?

It should be noted that the client does not have any development environment to this application, and is very unlikely to be anything but an end user.

[image: Error message box with title "Application Error": Exception EReadError in module pixellated.exe at 000200DB. Error reading HotImageList.Bitmap: Invalid ImageList1]

(note: I had to blur a few details in the image for security reasons, I hope this should not affect the general question)

Comment: Hint: Try Alt+PrntScr to create screenshots.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand of course, but I only have this from the customer, unfortunately. I am unable to replicate the issue here.

Comment: I realised that was probably the case after I had already written the comment, sorry! Well, at least it is a pretty moiré pattern.

Comment: In the mainform of the application, the list in question is simply `XXXXHotImageList: TImageList;`

Comment: There were all sorts of weird things with D6 image lists. Things like graphics drivers made a difference. What you really need here to dig deeper is a detailed report on the state of your program when this error is raised. Tools like madExcept and EurekaLog will give you that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the heads-up. I have asked the customer if anything in their environment has changed. This program is working in thousands of installations, for 10+ years, this is first time I see this particular error.  I will see if madExcept or EurekaLog can be used - but customer does not have, and will not have, development environment. Only executable.

Comment: Yes. The entire point of madExcept, EurekaLog etc. is this exact situation. It's so that you don't need to be helpless in the face of an error that you can't attach a debugger to.

Comment: I had the same error recently. Reason: I accidentally resized a BMP file to dimensions lImgWidth=0, lImgHeight=0 , then added this to the image list with FImageList.Width  := lImgWidth; FImageList.Height := lImgHeight; and  FImageList.Add(lBMP,nil);  **That third statement** is where the error occured, not at the earlier moment of creation of the TImageList. The Add calls HandleNeeded, which does: if FHandle = 0 then CreateImageList; (Don't ask me why Fhandle was 0 at that moment, I stopped debugging there and fixed my code)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this to just be a follow up: your code could access any `.Bitmap` and due to bad pointers overwrite parts of the `TImageList`. Ask the customer if he can reproduce this error, then try to reproduce it yourself.

---

As per Delphi 5 sources (don't have them for 6 or 7) this happens in:

```
procedure TCustomImageList.CreateImageList;
...
begin
  FHandle := ImageList_Create(...);
  if FHandle = 0 then raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SInvalidImageList);
```

...and that's also the only place where `SInvalidImageList` is ever used. [`ImageList_Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_create) may fail, but there's no chance to find out why. One possible reason is that COMCTL32.DLL indeed is a "wrong" one and your customer now has a version of it that behaves differently, while all the years before it was another (and now nobody knows which).

Comment: I would have prefered a comment, too, but it's too long and needs too much formattings to be a comment either.

Comment: Seeing this code: Memory issue maybe? (Or anything related: too many resources/handles/...)

Comment: You can try to get the version info of the `comctl32.dll` that’s being loaded. Then compare it to another systems version...